# CLion says 'Process finished with exit code 127'

Tags: c, cmake, compilation, clion

So I am running a sample c code Hello World project that appears when you make a new c project:

`main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

`CMakeLists.txt:`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(untitled1 C)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99) 
add_library(untitled1 library.c library.h main.c)
```

When I press Run, earlier it was giving me "error 12, permission denied" so I modified the file permissions. Now I am getting the following in the Run window:

```
/Users/alan/CLionProjects/untitled1/library.c

Process finished with exit code 127
```

I googled but cant seem to find any solution.

The following is the image of the preferences:

[image]
[image]

Comment: you've found the executable and have execute permissions on it? Does it execute and you see Hello World?

Comment: Looks to me like you're trying to run the C program directly without first compiling it into an executable.

Comment: @no the terminal just shows the above message. I dont see any main.o in the directroy

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker, the run command compiles it as I get "Build finished in 278 ms"

Comment: might be worth your time to find the executable and try to run (and build) it outside of the IDE (is this XCode?). Could a window pop up really quick, display Hello World, then disappear? That's the behavior you'd see running this in Visual Studio. The 127 return code could be the parent process of your Hello World process (maybe some debugging sandbox?) and not the return code of  your Hello World executable... 127 can't be the return code of your Hello World executable.. it returns 0. Perhaps try putting `getchar();` or a sleep before `return 0;` to make a pop up terminal linger.

Comment: I wanted to install XCode but its quite massive in size, so I am using CLion. Thats the thing, I dont see any terminal poping up. If I cant find the option I will have to download that massive XCode.

Comment: oh sorry, I'm dumb... had it in my mind CLion was the OS X flavor .. that's just Lion. A terminal pop could be happening really quick, try inserting one of the delay tactics from my prev comment. Also, as a sanity check, you could cut out CLion all together and try everything from the command line. Recent versions of OS X use the clang compiler I believe. Should just be able to open a terminal, cd to your source code, then "clang library.c" then "./a.out" .. or whatever the exact particulars for your system are.

Comment: hey! amazing! clang thing works out! I didnt know it existed! you did save me from the hassle of downloading XCode

Comment: @yano yes same behavior, dont see anything popping up. I really cant figure out what is the error about because it builds just fine but there is no object code.  I might simply use the terminal with clang if I cant resolve this.

Comment: AFAIK, that's the default compiler that OS X uses as of 2-3 years ago. An IDE is (_should be_) completely separate from the compiler, you can mix and match them at will. The IDE is the front end, the compiler is the back end. Even if you downloaded XCode, it would use whatever compiler you configured it to use (clang by default).. same with CLion. So it sounds like your problem is something with CLion setup.... if there is in fact a problem, I'm still curious if you see the same behavior after inserting [`sleep(5);`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) before `return 0;`.

Comment: hmmm ok. Yeah if you don't want to look into it any further, you can do all your code editing in the IDE and get all its benefits there, then simply compile and run from the terminal. Probably something simple tho, or maybe you're just looking in the wrong place for the output? Dunno, I'm not familiar with CLion, hopefully someone else can help you out.

Comment: @yano yes u did get me going. The only problem with terminal execution is unlike IDE it doesnt tell you which line is throwing error, it just tells you error code.

Comment: the OPs posted code will not cleanly compile!  The problem is the code is missing the statement: `#include <stdio.h>` so there will be a prototype for the function: `printf()`

Comment: 1. Please provide your `CMakeLists.txt`. 2. Add the include as mentioned in comment above. 3. What window do you see the message in, is it a compilation or run window?

Comment: @VictorSergienko 1. ```cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(untitled1 C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

add_library(untitled1 library.c library.h main.c) ``` 2. Edited in Question 3. It happens in run window

Comment: @VictorSergienko The generated object code works fine when I execute it through MacOS terminal, it prints "Hello, World" however, I just get the code 127 in the run window

Comment: @VictorSergienko I dont get an results instead get 127 code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to run a library. Modifying file permissions by hand is not the way to make it work, you could as well try running an arbitrary random file.

In order to make an executable, you need to use [`add_executable`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_executable.html).

What you are running is not called an object file. I recommend reading some introduction like [this one](https://medium.com/@meghamohan/everything-you-need-to-know-about-libraries-in-c-e8ad6138cbb4).

Also, if you want to create a library and link against it, you need to describe it with `add_library` using `library.c`, and then an executable with `add_executable` using `main.c`. Then link the executable to the library with [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html). Here's a [CMake tutorial](http://derekmolloy.ie/hello-world-introductions-to-cmake/) that may help.

Comment: I shall take a look and get back if I have questions.